# Spring cloud AWS kinesis stream binder failed to start due to improper bean initialization

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I am trying to run this simple kinesis message consumer with the following code. This is the only class in application

I am facing this error since, I have updated to latest snapshot version of kinesis binder

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    @EnableBinding(Sink.class)
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class ProducerApplication {



      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerApplication.class, args);
      }

      @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
      public void listen(String message) {
        System.out.println("Message has been received"+message);
      }

    }
```

Application yml

```
server.port: 8081


spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: my.sink
          content-type: application/json




cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: us-east-1
    credentials:
      accessKey: <accessKey>
      secretKey: <secretKey>
```

build.gradle

```
     buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    group = 'com.kinesis.demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

I am getting the bean initialzation exception and there seems to be a problem in creating bean `DynamoDbMetadataStore`.

```
2018-07-10 10:53:22.629  INFO 18332 --- [esis-consumer-1] a.i.k.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : Got an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component has not been initialized: DynamoDbMetadataStore{table={SpringIntegrationMetadataStore: {AttributeDefinitions: [{AttributeName: KEY,AttributeType: S}],TableName: SpringIntegrationMetadataStore,KeySchema: [{AttributeName: KEY,KeyType: HASH}],TableStatus: ACTIVE,CreationDateTime: Wed Jun 27 10:51:53 IST 2018,ProvisionedThroughput: {NumberOfDecreasesToday: 0,ReadCapacityUnits: 1,WriteCapacityUnits: 1},TableSizeBytes: 0,ItemCount: 0,TableArn: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:1234567:table/SpringIntegrationMetadataStore,TableId: d0cf588b-e122-406b-ad82-06255dfea6d4,}}, createTableRetries=25, createTableDelay=1, readCapacity=1, writeCapacity=1, timeToLive=null}.
 Is it declared as a bean? during [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=LATEST, sequenceNumber='null', timestamp=null, stream='my.sink', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=NEW}] task invocation.
Process will be retried on the next iteration.
```

This error started after updating to latest snapshot version of kinesis binder.

Can you please check if some thing is wrong.

Comment: Can you just share with us a simple project somewhere on Git Hub? Also I'm not aware about `cloud.aws.kinesis.endpoint` configuration property. What is that? Who and how uses it ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thank you for looking into it. I have added sample project here https://github.com/patan12/spring-kinesis-poc
Can you please check and help

Comment: There is no significance for this property cloud.aws.kinesis.endpoint . I removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just fixed the issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/commit/fc34f814e557936d1bcb815d0879bd4f6e035675

The problem was that when we have already a table in the DynamoDB, we just return from the `afterPropertiesSet()` leaving the `initialized` as `false`.

The latest `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` should work now.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get this error, is it due to access issues. c.a.s.d.AmazonDynamoDBLockClient         : Could not acquire lock because of a client side failure in talking to DDB

com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:iam::123:user/aws-kinesis-dev is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123:table/SpringIntegrationLockRegistry (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: R5S2G137V3NN625GD52ASOHG4BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)

Comment: `User: arn:aws:iam::123:user/aws-kinesis-dev is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource:`. That's already out of Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder project responsibility. You need to grant those permissions to the use `GetItem`.

Comment: After granting enough permission, it worked. Thank you